Why doesn't my code delete the file from device storage?
My Android application stores images of vehicles from the device's camera in the device storage (/data/files/image1.jpg, /data/files/image2.jpg, etc.), but I can't delete them.
Vehicles are presented in a Jetpack Compose screen with a Card composable and a LazyColumn composable. Each card has a "Delete" button which works, except if I delete a card between two others, the card after the deleted one displays the photo of the deleted one instead of its own.
I'm deleting the database record which has a field "imagepath" of type TEXT first, so I should be able to delete the image file from the device storage. A function in the ViewModel deletes both the record and image file, but file.delete() does not delete it:
fun deleteVehicle(id:Int,fileName:String){
    viewModelScope.launch{
        val directory = context.filesDir
        val file = File(directory, fileName)
        try{
            repository.deleteVehicle(id)
            if(file.exists()){
                file.delete()
            }
        }catch(e:Exception){
            Log.e("ViewModel:","Error while trying to delete the vehicle: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}

How I'm capturing the image from camera:
val lanzador = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()
) { bitmap: Bitmap? ->
if (bitmap != null) {
  val file = File(contexto.filesDir,
"${viewModel.listaVehiculos.value.size}.jpg") // Or .png
 try {
    FileOutputStream(file).use { out ->
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out) // Or PNG
    }
    imageBitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap()
 } catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
 }
}
}

The only way I can display the correct photo in the corresponding Card composable is by navigating to the same screen again.

"in the device storage (/data/files/image1.jpg, /data/files/image2.jpg, etc.)" -- I am not aware of any Android device that has a directory structure like that. Are you certain that those are actual values? "I'm developing an Android application which stores images of vehicles" -- you might consider editing your [mcve] to show your code that creates the image files, so we can better compare that with your deletion code. For example, perhaps the value of fileName that you are passing into deleteVehicle() is incorrect. Personally, I would skip the exists() check.

Looks like the issue is that the actual image isn't getting deleted or the wrong image is, and only its record from the database is removed. Probably that's why the supposedly deleted image is appearing in other places. You can keep the name of the image file along with the id in the database and show the connected image when displaying. Still, if the image you're trying to delete isn't getting deleted, even if you solve the issue by following what I mentioned, image files are going to accumulate, which isnt good. Log whether the image file supposedly deleted still exist or not
